# I need to press button twice before accessing camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm currently working on an Android app that allows me to access the camera and upon clicking one button, I switch to the front cam. I click another button, I go back to the rear cam. However, I'm facing a problem upon clicking the buttons.
If I'm at the rear cam(Which is the default option when I start the app) and I click the front cam button, the cam pauses. It stays paused until I press the front button again and it switches to the front. Same thing happens to the rear cam. I checked the logcat and it says the "camera is idle". Has anyone experienced such a problem before?

Thank you

The way the cam opens is that it goes through the openCamera() and then to the statecallback function.

The openCamera() is used for the rear cam. The switchCam() is used for the front cam. I didnt know how to switch the cam so I used the same function but changed the index from 0 to 1.

```
private void openCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
    try {
        cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        assert map != null;
        imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[2];
        // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
       // manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
}


protected void switchCam() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
    try {
        cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        assert map != null;
        imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[2];
        // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
}


private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
        //This is called when the camera is open
        Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");

        cameraDevice = camera;

        createCameraPreview();
    }



    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
    }


    public void onPause(CameraDevice camera){
        cameraDevice=camera;
    }
};
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Sure thing. I edited my post.